# Why doesn't Z3 BitVec object have runtime size info?

Tags: c++, z3, bitvector

I'm working with different sizes of Z3 bitvecs and I was working on a way to ease the workload. I'm going to get the info from an object before z3 expression was created so it's not actually a vital problem but I wondered why z3 bitvecs doesn't carry runtime size information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely query the `sort` of every z3 AST term, and then get the size for `bv`s; so, yes, they do carry size information along with pretty much everything you need to know.

The relevant calls are:

- [get_sort](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3_1_1expr.html#a527131da05acd3775a8e3fac627e25ec)
- [bv_size](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3_09_09_8h_source.html#l00594)

The API documentation has myriad other calls for scrutinizing different parts of terms, see [here](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3.html).